# Url for pages in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

Ok.is it possible to set url for the pages of type "localhost:5454/user/details/1" to localhost:5454/somenameofuser .. can i do it in mvc4? "somenameofuser" is an url for concrete page. I want to set this field to the class user. and this field would unikalnym..thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it you are trying to achieve? Explain it further. But as for my understanding, You could try and create a routing that will match a url of /somenameofuser

`routes.MapRoute (
"Default", // Route name
"/{nameofuser}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Controller here", action = "Action here" } // Parameter defaults
);`

Comment: thanks for answer, Bon! My task is: Url for pages must be very simple and beauty for SEO. Url, that look at localhost:5454/user/details/1 is very ugly for eyes of my director, he want to see url looak at localhost:5454/somenameofuser.. im really newest in routing.. im try your example.. thank you!